# Different default value of an attribute in different attribute sets

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, product-attribute, products-management, attribute-set

I have attribute sets which I use when adding new products. All products have a weight attribute. I know you can set up a default value which will appear along all attribute sets with that attribute. My question is can I set up different default weight for each attribute set? and if so any tips on how I can achieve it would be highly helpful.

I use Magento Commerce 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. With default Magento, you can't. But there are ways. I'd recommend creating an extension that listens to the catalog_product_save_before event in the adminhtml scope.

Create the file `app/etc/modules/Your_Module.xml` with the following content;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Next up, `app/code/local/Your/Module/etc/config.xml`, where we declare the event to listen for and which method to execute;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_load_after>
                <observers>
                    <your_module>
                        <class>Your_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>setDefaultWeightValue</method>
                    </your_module>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_load_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <your_module>
                <class>Your_Module_Model</class>
            </your_module>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

And finally, `app/code/local/Your/Module/Model/Observer.php`, where we set the predefined weights for the different attribute set IDs and where we assign the value to the product currently opened;

```
<?php

class Your_Module_Model_Observer {

    // This is the default value you would like to use
    const DEFAULT_WEIGHT = 50;

    // Change this if you have set a default value on the attribute other than empty
    const DEFAULT_WEIGHT_SETTING_MAGENTO = '0.0000';

    public function setDefaultWeightValue($observer) {
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();
        if($_product->getWeight() == self::DEFAULT_WEIGHT_SETTING_MAGENTO) {
            $_product->setWeight(
                $this->getWeightsPerAttributeSet($_product->getAttributeSetId())
            );
        }
    }

    public function getWeightsPerAttributeSet($attributeSetId) {
        $weightsPerAttribuetSet = array(
            4 => 100,
            5 => 200,
            6 => 300
        );

        if(isset($weightsPerAttribuetSet[$attributeSetId])) {
            return $weightsPerAttribuetSet[$attributeSetId];
        } else {
            return self::DEFAULT_WEIGHT;
        }
    }

}
```

This will only work for existing products, since new products aren't loaded and thus won't fire the event.

Answer (score 2):

I would create an observer for `catalog_product_save_before`, which is triggered the first time, when this form is submitted:

[image: New Product]

which saves the product with id, type and attribute set and redirects you to the *edit* page. So ther you will see the new default values that you choose dynamically based on the attribute set.

To prevent saving them again on subsequent saves, use `isObjectNew()`:

```
if ($product->isObjectNew()) {
    // set default values here, based on attribute set
}
```