# Set default value to news_from_date and news_to_date

Tags: product-attribute, magento-1, products-management, new-products

How can I automatically set the news_from_date and the news_to_date for a new product?

news_from_date should be the date now and news_to_date should be date now +1 week.

Comment: Do you want to do this in the Admin? Via the Dataflow importer? Via PHP?

Answer (score 1):

This answer explains how to use dynamic default values: [Different default value of an attribute in different attribute sets](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58395/different-default-value-of-an-attribute-in-different-attribute-sets/97708#97708)

You can apply the same here, i.e. create an observer for `catalog_product_save_before`, with code like this:

```
$product = $observer->getProduct();
if ($product->isObjectNew()) {
    $product->setNewsFromDate(now());
    $product->setNewsToDate(strtotime('+1 week'));
}
```